# How do I put a newline inside a "set /p" in batch

Tags: batch-file, newline

I'm trying to insert a new line inside the set /p variable prompt, here's an example.

```
set /p variableName=[1] - this\n[2] - or this

output:
[1] - this
[2] - or this
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make far more sense to simply `echo [1] - this` and then `set /p "variablename=[2] - or this"`? Or `echo` _both_ and then have no prompt at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like SomethingDark suggests, you could use simply `echo` for the lines

```
echo [1] This
set /p "var=[2] - or this "
```

But if you insist on only using `set /p` it can be done with

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(set \n=^
%=empty=%
)
set /p "var=[1] This!\n![2] or this"
```

Comment: @iNeedHelpWithThisCode, I appreciate you accepting my answer, but jeb's answer beats mine.  I've never been on the asking end, so i don't know if you change his to the accepted answer, but you should if you can.  He is doing what I had no clue could be done.  His code actually works!  I mostly understand his code, but I have to admit I'm shocked that it works.  I think the `%=empty=%` is a non-existing variable, that prior to the parenthesis didn't exist, and expands to nothing.  But why you need that , and how did anyone ever come up with that, is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it doesn't work the way you are thinking.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5552995/4190564), and created the following code where the variable `PText` contains the lines you want, then is used as the prompt in the `SET /P` command:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET PText=[1] - this^& ECHO;[2] - or this
SET /P variableName=%PText%
ECHO;Answer=[%variableName%]
```

When I run the code, it prints `[1] - this`, I answer `ABC` and press enter, it then prints `[2] - or this`, and the following `ECHO` command prints `Answer=[ABC]`:

```
[1] - thisABC
[2] - or this
Answer=[ABC]
```

I believe the only real answer would be to either `ECHO` what you want prior to doing the `SET /P`, or use the `CHOICE` command as described on [this page](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/choice.php).

Example `SET /P`:

```
ECHO;[1] - this
ECHO;[2] - or this
SET /P variableName=[1,2]?
```

Comment: No. The code you posted (which is non working and never will as it is a macro) is not the same code OP posted, it is therefore irrelevant.

Comment: PS. The code op posted is an example of what he requires and was not meant to be a working example. Just what was expected.

Answer (score 0):

To actually insert a newline into the text:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set nl=^


::The Above empty lines are critical for this function, do not delete.
set /p "var=[1] - this!nl![2] - or this!nl!"
echo %var%
```

Personally I am not sure why you do not use `choice` for this?

```
echo [1] - This & echo [2] - or this & choice /c 12
```